# How do i validate two component's value are same or not? JSF

Tags: jsf

As we have comparevalidator in Asp.Net, what do we have in JSF to validate whether two field's value are same or not? I want to validate password and confirmPassword field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, such a validator does not exist in the basic JSF implementation. You basically need to run the validator on the *last* component of the group and grab the *other* component you'd like to validate as well using [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uicomponentbase#findComponent-java.lang.String-). E.g.

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    UIComponent otherComponent = context.getViewRoot().findComponent("otherClientId");
    Object otherValue = ((UIInput) otherComponent).getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Also see [this article](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html) for more background info and concrete examples.

On the other hand, if you're already on JSF2, then you can also make use of ajaxical validation:

```
<h:form>
    <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.validate}" />
     ...
</h:form>
```

..where `#{bean.validate}` method look like this:

```
public void validate(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
    UIComponent form = e.getComponent();
    UIComponent oneComponent = form.findComponent("oneClientId");
    UIComponent otherComponent = form.findComponent("otherClientId");
    // ...
}
```

Also see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130307134500/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/) for more JSF2 validation examples.

If you're using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org), then you could use [`<o:validateEqual>`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual). It also allows setting a custom message. The [showcase](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual) has a live example demonstrating the common usecase of validating the password confirmation. You don't even need ajax to update the model before invoking the validator.

Here's the minimum necessary code:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{signup.person.password}" />
<h:message for="password" />

<h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" />
<h:message for="confirmPassword" />

<o:validateEqual components="password confirmPassword" 
    message="Passwords do not match!" showMessageFor="confirmPassword" />
```

No additional Java code needed.