# How to validate two fields in JSF 2.0 without Bean Validaiton

Tags: jsf-2

I want to validate that two fields on a page match (e.g. are the same exact email address). I don't have access to bean validation/validation groups. How should I go about validating that both addresses match?

Current thought is to put a validator on the second field and have it check that it matches the submitted value of the first. Is this the best way or is there a way to do this via configuration or some other means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2.0 doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: Another example with ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489893/how-validate-two-password-fields-by-ajax/7493527#7493527

Comment: Core JavaServer Faces Third Edition (3rd publishing) mentions an alternative that uses "Multi-Component Validation" using the postValidate event as a hook. Would this be a bad way to do it?

Comment: You could also do so. This would only tight couple the validator to the particular components, making it unreuseable for other use cases having the same requirement to validate multiple fields on equality. You'd basically need to copy the postvalidate event method and change the client IDs of the components of interest.

Comment: Thanks, note, just realized you proposed this solution in another thread. Am linking it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456272/how-do-i-validate-two-components-value-are-same-or-not-jsf.

Comment: Have you tried `<o:validateEqual>`? See also this showcase example: http://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/validators/validateEqual.xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are an aggregate of all solutions so far:

See

1) [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Ajaxified solution:
2) [How validate two password fields by ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489893/how-validate-two-password-fields-by-ajax/7493527#7493527)

PostValidate solution:
3) [How do i validate two component's value are same or not? JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456272/how-do-i-validate-two-components-value-are-same-or-not-jsf)